# what filters affect ffmpeg encoding speed

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

What are the options in this command that would cause my encoding speed to be 0.999x instead of 1.0x or higher?

```
ffmpeg -y \
-loop 1 -framerate 30 -re \
-i ./1280x720.jpg \
-stream_loop -1 -re \
-i ./audio.mp3 \
-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-b:v 2500k -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 10000k \
-preset slow -tune stillimage \
-b:a 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec aac \
-af "dynaudnorm=f=150:g=15" \
-g 60 \
-f flv tmp.flv
```

I am trying to figure out why would this only be encoding at 0.999x speed, is there anything that I could do to speed this up? 2 pass encoding? I cannot understand why the encoding speed is so slow?

Also please not i've tried present from slow - ultrafast, the encoding speed stays relatively unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-re` is the rate-limiting factor. It only feeds input in real-time so the encoder can't progress any faster.

Remove the `-re` before the inputs. Needed only when trying to simulate a real-time input or streaming to an output that expects its input in real-time.